# JQuery. Сортировка элементов с рандомным порядком классов

Tags: javascript, jquery, сортировка

Имеется массив элементов в рандомном порядке:

```html
<div class="item1"></div>
<div class="item2"></div>
<div class="item1"></div>
<div class="item1"></div>
<div class="item1"></div>
<div class="item2"></div>
<div class="item1"></div>
<div class="item1"></div>
<div class="item2"></div>
<div class="item2"></div>
<div class="item1"></div>
<div class="item1"></div>
<div class="item2"></div>
<div class="item1"></div>
```

Нужно добиться того, чтобы за элементом item1 всегда следовал item2, а лишние элементы отображались в конце все вместе. Т.е.:

```html
<div class="item1"></div>
<div class="item2"></div>
<div class="item1"></div>
<div class="item2"></div>
<div class="item1"></div>
<div class="item2"></div>
<div class="item1"></div>
<div class="item2"></div>
<div class="item1"></div>
<div class="item2"></div>
<div class="item1"></div>
<div class="item1"></div>
<div class="item1"></div>
<div class="item1"></div>
```

Как этого можно добиться?

Comment: `Имеется массив элементов`.... А где он имеется? в JS где-то? Если есть какой-то js код, его (массив элементов) содержащий - неплохо было бы на него взглянуть, чтобы понять с чем вы работаете

Comment: В HTML, уже на выходе. Надо настроить отображение.

Comment: @ЕленаСеменова, стоит добавить результирующую разметку, то есть, что должно выйти в итоге, если на входе будет указанная разметка

Answer (score 1):

Получилось в итоге сделать:

```
  var container = $(".items");
  var n=0;
  $(".item2" ).each(function(){
   var a = $('.item1:eq('+n+')');
   $(this).insertBefore($('.item1:eq('+n+')'));
   n++;
  });
```

Comment: Только у вас так начинается всё с `item2`, а не с `item1` как вы писали в вопросе....и... если `item2` больше будет чем `item1` - не получится что-то там еще скорее всего